# Java compare different Object by common property

Tags: java, list, properties, compare, contains

I have `ObjectA` & `ObjectB`. Both have a `property` called `ID` `(Long)`.
I have 2 `List`, `ListA` which contains objects type `ObjectA` and `ListB` which contains objects type `ObjectB`.

I want to fill `ListC`, with all the objects from `ListA` and `ListB` but without duplicates.

I cannot use the `contains` method because `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` are different objects, I have to compare by the property `ID`.

I know the best solution would be that `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` `extends` a `Super class`, but I cannot change that for now, I just have to find a temporally solution to make it work.

I have try this:

```
listC.addAll(listA);    

for(int j=0; j<ListA.size(); j++) {
    for(int k=0; k<ListB.size(); k++) {
        ObjectA objectA = ((ObjectA)listA.get(j));
        ObjectB objectB = ((ObjectB)listB.get(k));

        if(!objectA.getId().equals(objectB.getId())) {
            listC.add(objectB);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm going crazy with it.

Comment: objectB.getId() bracket missed  while `equal` check. also last one

Comment: What type does the property ID have? something like`int` ?

Comment: If ID property is your own class, you need to override equals() method.

Comment: @bmt sorry, my mistake copying + pasting. Edited

Comment: ID property is a Long

Comment: You would be better of with a `Map<ID, SuperInterface>` for each one and you can just add one to the other.  While avoiding adding a super interface might seem simpler, it is actually making your life more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an "efficient" solution you could implement a `HashSet<Long>` which is holding all yet used `ID`s.

```
HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();
for (ObjectA objA: listA) {
    list.add(objA);
    ids.add(objA.getId());
}

for (ObjectB objB: listB) {
    if (!ids.contains(objB.getId())) {
        ids.add(objB.getId());
        list.add(objB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If they both have the same property, write an interface (that's why they are there) which has only the value ID (maybe with a getter) and implement it in your Classes ObjectA and ObjectB. Then you can write your own Comparator (with type of your Interface) or since you only need equals, just override this method (that wouldn't be clean). This should be the cleanest way.

Answer (score 3):

For a solution for which you don't need to touch your classes at all, you could implement a `java.util.Comparator` 
like e.g.

```
public class ObjectComparator implements java.util.Comparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        long id1 = -1L;
        long id2 = -1L;
        if(o1 instanceof ObjectA) {
            id1 = ((ObjectA)o1).getId();
        }
        if(o1 instanceof ObjectB) {
            id1 = ((ObjectB)o1).getId();
        }
        if(o2 instanceof ObjectA) {
            id2 = ((ObjectA)o2).getId();
        }
        if(o2 instanceof ObjectB) {
            id2 = ((ObjectB)o2).getId();
        }
        return Long.valueOf(id1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(id2));
    }
}
```

Then you could simply use a `java.util.TreeSet` to remove duplicates for you:

```
Set distinct = new TreeSet(new ObjectComparator());
distinct.addAll(listA);
distinct.addAll(listB);
```

Of course you will get compiler warnings for using raw types, but it should work.

Comment: very nice solution too. Thanks!